# Deferencing Null pointer

Tags: java

```
public class Model
{
    public static Connection getConnection()
    {
        Connection conn = null;
    try
    {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe",       "System", "system");
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return conn;
}

public static class Cart
{
    public String itmName="";
    public int howmany=0;
    public static long itmQty=0, itmID=0;
    public double itmPrice=0.0, itmCost=0.0, totalSum=0.0;
} 

public static ArrayList<Cart> getCartDatabase(String user) throws Exception
{
    Connection conn = getConnection();
    String sql = "select * from userCarts where userID = '" + user + "'";
    PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet rst = pstmt.executeQuery();
    ArrayList<Cart> al = null;
    Cart crt=null;
    while(rst.next())
    {
        System.out.println("CPoint");
        try
        {
            long p = rst.getLong("itemID"); 
            crt.itmID = p; // This is the line thats creating the error
            System.out.println(p + " is long! I guess...");
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e)
        {
            System.out.println("NPE Caught in Model");
        }
        System.out.println("CP 1 " + crt.itmID);
        ArrayList<row> alr=null; 
        try
        {
            alr = Model.getStoreInventory();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("CP 2");
        for(int i=0; i<alr.size(); i++)
        {
            crt.itmName = alr.get(i).itmName;
            crt.itmPrice = alr.get(i).itmPrice;
            crt.itmQty = alr.get(i).itmQty;
        }
        System.out.println("CP 3");
        crt.howmany = rst.getInt("howmany");
        crt.itmCost = crt.itmPrice*crt.howmany;
        al.add(crt);
    }
    return al;
    }
}
```

When I try to access this method of `getCartFromDatabase`, it gives a `NullPointerException` however I don't understand why it would do this. Moreover, I tried to make the class as a non static class too, but still it gave the same error:

> "Possible deferencing Null Pointer"

Comment: Can you post stacktrace? On which line are you getting a NPE?

Comment: Do you get a real `NullPointerException` at runtime? Or are you getting a `Possible deferencing Null Pointer` warning at compile time? The java compiler usually does not emit such warnings, are you using FindBugs or a similar tool?

Comment: Never catch `NPE`s explicitely in your code, unless you have a very good reason to do so. Catching any `RuntimeException` is only advised if you make the exception visible in any way, else you have no way to know what is going on.

Comment: Check if your oracle listener is working and OracleDb too. You dont know that because you catch exception throwing by DriverManager.

Comment: run:
CPoint
1234567890 is long! I guess...
CP 1 1234567890
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.Model.getCartDatabase(Model.java:336)
CP 2
 at com.TEST.main(TEST.java:34)
Java Result: 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Cart crt=null;
while(rst.next())
{
    System.out.println("CPoint");
    try
    {
        long p = rst.getLong("itemID"); 
        crt.itmID = p; // This is the line thats creating the error
        System.out.println(p + " is long! I guess...");
    }
```

`crt` is `null` when you try to access `crt.itemID`. You have to assign it an instance first.

I think you may simply change the first line from the snippet to

```
Cart crt = new Cart();
```

Comment: This helped quite a lot... but now there's error on line al.add(crt)
CPoint
1234567890 is long! I guess...
CP 1 1234567890
CP 2
CP 3
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.Model.getCartDatabase(Model.java:343)
 at com.TEST.main(TEST.java:34)
Java Result: 1

Comment: Thank you!. The arraylist was also not initialized. Now initialized it & got it.... Really appreciate it!